# How can the length of a collection be different from the number of .each-executions?

Tags: jquery

I fear I am misunderstanding something essential about `filter()` and `each`.
What I believe I understood:

- `filter()` filters a set of elements and returns a collection
- `each`runs a bit of code on each element of a collection

Here's the bit of code that makes me doubt my understanding:

```
    var t1 = $(pnt).filter(":not([class~='collapse'])");
    console.info("length", t1.length);
    t1.each(console.info(this));
```

The first statement builds a collection. 2line  prints the number of elements in the collection and the 3d statement logs every element of that collection.

These 3 are a consecutive lines of a function that I wrote (the whole things is too much, I fear, to do a fiddle).
When I execute this code, the first log-entry is `4` and the second is a list of 7 elements. How can the two logs created by these statements differ?

Comment: I'd expect `t1.each()`  to want a function definition, not an execution, ie `function() {console.info(this);}`.

Comment: You need to put the `console.info()` call in an anonymous function and then pass that to `each()`. As the code stands the `console.info()` call is executed immediately then the *result* of that operation is passed to `each()` to be executed against each element in the set

Comment: The second list of 7 elements, are they the right elements? If you run each properly, https://jsfiddle.net/q6u57ptr/ it produces the right result

Comment: Consider: what is actually being shown with `console.info(this)` in `t1.each(console.info(this))` - in the provided code, it's undefined - it's *not* the iteration, which would be `t1.each(function() { console.info(this); })`

Comment: If you would run the code as it is, not wrapped in anything else, the third line would output not a collection of seven elements but `window`

Comment: Thanks guys - got it!! @tyler-roper - if you want to post you comment as a answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @MBaas I think this is very likely a duplicate, I just can't dig for a valid match at this moment. As such, I'm not sure this warrants an answer, I appreciate it though!